# How do I fix this EXC_BAD_ACCESS in NSPropertyListSerialization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I am using NSPropertyListSerialization to sync a NSDictionary via the Dropbox Sync API. Writing to a file works fine and it shows up in Dropbox, but trying to read it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Here's how I'm writing to dropbox:

```
//Create the dictionary, add the necessary stuff then do this.
NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:syncPlistDictionary
                                                              format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                             options:0
                                                               error:NULL];
    DBError *error = nil;
    [syncFile writeData:data error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Dropbox Error writing to file: %@", error);
    }
    [syncFile close];
```

This works fine and it never logs that error.

However, when I try to read it later, it crashes.
Here's how I'm reading the file: (The data parameter comes from the dropbox file. The dropbox SDK does not give an error when getting this either.)

```
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithContentsOfData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSData *myData = [data copy];
    if ([myData length]==0) {
        return [[[NSDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    }
    if (!myData) {
        return nil;
    }
    // uses toll-free bridging for data into CFDataRef and CFPropertyList into NSDictionary
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:myData
                                                                         options:0
                                                                          format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                                           error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"NSDictionary Helper Error: %@", error); //This never gets logged because it crashes before getting here.
    }
    //[myData release]; //I commented this out thinking I was probably releasing it to fast but it made no difference.
    return dictionary;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @CarterPape no I'm not

Comment: I'm voting to close, this question could have been answered by a quick look at the documentation of the API which indicates that the format argument is a pointer indicating what kind of property list was read, not an indicator of which format to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithContentsOfData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSData *myData = [data copy];
    if ([myData length]==0) {
        return [[[NSDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    }
    if (!myData) {
        return nil;
    }
    // uses toll-free bridging for data into CFDataRef and CFPropertyList into NSDictionary
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPropertyListFormat plistFormat;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:myData
                                                                         options:0
                                                                          format:&plistFormat
                                                                           error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"NSDictionary Helper Error: %@", error);
    }
    [myData release];
    return dictionary;
}
```

All I had to do was: `NSPropertyListFormat plistFormat;` and `format:&plistFormat` instead of `format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0`